# Pbkdf2_sha256 encryption

Tags: python, hash, pbkdf2

Hello everyone so I'm figuring out how Pbkdf2_sha256 works.

Here are some of the cracked hashes I'm currently studying

```
PBKDF2 pbkdf2_sha256$10000$005OtPxTXhPq$K/2GplWPJsBVj+qbgdKW8YEteQyUkIiquT5MaOhPo4Y=:harry
PBKDF2 pbkdf2_sha256$10000$00Qhibr5Mbeg$l9grYueDrl3qN3NA7e9j5PodgV1XkGTz0Z6ajhF99AY=:radio
PBKDF2 pbkdf2_sha256$10000$00h7h0g1ZKE1$YEobSm/y+cFg/VXhU4gGYJ6eOkZ68jhJ5axDu68Dack=:momo
PBKDF2 pbkdf2_sha256$10000$01JMkfGk1RXh$vD+GGZshw5kExtZOpl5+Lht3xECULdbNVOesoTicxto=:fred
PBKDF2 pbkdf2_sha256$10000$01vkw1viCg4J$2hjlbq10Jh/Su3yqjKfYCnCSt1WlKcKJtsqDET618M0=:get
PBKDF2 pbkdf2_sha256$10000$01wayF5JLVSZ$2/9COWqb6SZG/raqabtU8fNBzkrt2puN7SaKw0U7jBs=:987456321
```

And here is my code and output for calculating the hash

```
>>> from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256
>>> from passlib.utils.binary import ab64_decode
>>> print(pbkdf2_sha256.hash("harry", rounds=10000, salt=ab64_decode(b'005OtPxTXhPq')))
$pbkdf2-sha256$10000$005OtPxTXhPq$l9LhRMPBW.EEdlBE9b.P0Z70Kxidl9EJhfGK7FiLUHA
```

Comparing these two and you can see a difference.

```
$pbkdf2_sha256$10000$005OtPxTXhPq$K/2GplWPJsBVj+qbgdKW8YEteQyUkIiquT5MaOhPo4Y=
$pbkdf2-sha256$10000$005OtPxTXhPq$l9LhRMPBW.EEdlBE9b.P0Z70Kxidl9EJhfGK7FiLUHA
```

Can someone please explain what causes this and how can I calculate the correct hash?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you know the "cracked" hashes are correct? The salts in those cracked hashes are suspiciously short.

Comment: The "cracked" hashes use a base64 encoding that is not used in Unix password hashes. The '+' character does not normally appear in such a hash. Also, the '=' padding character is omitted in Unix password hashes. That's evidence that something is amiss in the cracked hash list. Whatever format that is, it's not compatible with passlib

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk The hashes came from a hash cracking community, and I'm pretty sure the cracked ones are verified. The original list has some 75k lines, and all the salts are of the same length. The appended = does seem suspicious because it appears on all of the lines before :[plain]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comment, the posted data has a format different from *passlib*: The *passlib* format is explained [here](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.pbkdf2_digest.html#format-algorithm). Salt and hash (checksum) are Base64 encoded. A special Base64 variant is used that is explained [here](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.utils.binary.html#passlib.utils.binary.ab64_encode): Padding (`=`) and whitespaces are omitted and `.` is applied instead `+`.

The hash of the posted data on the other hand is standard Base64 encoded (i.e. with `+` instead of `.`) and with padding (`=`). **Furthermore the salt is UTF8 decoded.**

If this is taken into account the salts and hashes are identical. The following code determines the *passlib* data from the posted data and compares salt and hash, where salt and hash of the posted data are displayed in *passlib* format (i.e. with the *passlib* Base64 variant and Base64 encoded salt):

```
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256
from base64 import b64decode
from passlib.utils.binary import ab64_encode

def hashAndCompare(crackedHash):
    
    crackedChain = crackedHash.split('$')   
    #crackedChainDigest = crackedChain[0]
    crackedChainRounds = crackedChain[1]
    crackedChainSalt = crackedChain[2]
    crackedChainSaltPasslibFormat = ab64_encode(crackedChainSalt.encode('utf8')).decode('utf8')
    crackedChainHashData = crackedChain[3].split(':')
    crackedChainHash = crackedChainHashData[0]
    crackedChainHashPasslibFormat = ab64_encode(b64decode(crackedChainHash)).decode('utf8')
    crackedChainData = crackedChainHashData[1]
    
    passlibHash = pbkdf2_sha256.hash(crackedChainData, rounds=crackedChainRounds, salt=crackedChainSalt.encode('utf8')) 
    passlibChain = passlibHash.split('$')
    passlibChainSalt = passlibChain[3]
    passlibChainHash = passlibChain[4]
    
    print('Passlib: Hash: {0} Salt: {1}\nCracked: Hash: {2} Salt: {3}\n'.format(passlibChainHash, passlibChainSalt, crackedChainHashPasslibFormat, crackedChainSaltPasslibFormat))

hashAndCompare('pbkdf2_sha256$10000$005OtPxTXhPq$K/2GplWPJsBVj+qbgdKW8YEteQyUkIiquT5MaOhPo4Y=:harry')
hashAndCompare('pbkdf2_sha256$10000$00Qhibr5Mbeg$l9grYueDrl3qN3NA7e9j5PodgV1XkGTz0Z6ajhF99AY=:radio')
hashAndCompare('pbkdf2_sha256$10000$00h7h0g1ZKE1$YEobSm/y+cFg/VXhU4gGYJ6eOkZ68jhJ5axDu68Dack=:momo')
hashAndCompare('pbkdf2_sha256$10000$01JMkfGk1RXh$vD+GGZshw5kExtZOpl5+Lht3xECULdbNVOesoTicxto=:fred')
hashAndCompare('pbkdf2_sha256$10000$01vkw1viCg4J$2hjlbq10Jh/Su3yqjKfYCnCSt1WlKcKJtsqDET618M0=:get')
hashAndCompare('pbkdf2_sha256$10000$01wayF5JLVSZ$2/9COWqb6SZG/raqabtU8fNBzkrt2puN7SaKw0U7jBs=:987456321')
```

Salts and hashes are identical with consistent encoding:

```
Passlib: Hash: K/2GplWPJsBVj.qbgdKW8YEteQyUkIiquT5MaOhPo4Y Salt: MDA1T3RQeFRYaFBx
Cracked: Hash: K/2GplWPJsBVj.qbgdKW8YEteQyUkIiquT5MaOhPo4Y Salt: MDA1T3RQeFRYaFBx

Passlib: Hash: l9grYueDrl3qN3NA7e9j5PodgV1XkGTz0Z6ajhF99AY Salt: MDBRaGlicjVNYmVn
Cracked: Hash: l9grYueDrl3qN3NA7e9j5PodgV1XkGTz0Z6ajhF99AY Salt: MDBRaGlicjVNYmVn

Passlib: Hash: YEobSm/y.cFg/VXhU4gGYJ6eOkZ68jhJ5axDu68Dack Salt: MDBoN2gwZzFaS0Ux
Cracked: Hash: YEobSm/y.cFg/VXhU4gGYJ6eOkZ68jhJ5axDu68Dack Salt: MDBoN2gwZzFaS0Ux

Passlib: Hash: vD.GGZshw5kExtZOpl5.Lht3xECULdbNVOesoTicxto Salt: MDFKTWtmR2sxUlho
Cracked: Hash: vD.GGZshw5kExtZOpl5.Lht3xECULdbNVOesoTicxto Salt: MDFKTWtmR2sxUlho

Passlib: Hash: 2hjlbq10Jh/Su3yqjKfYCnCSt1WlKcKJtsqDET618M0 Salt: MDF2a3cxdmlDZzRK
Cracked: Hash: 2hjlbq10Jh/Su3yqjKfYCnCSt1WlKcKJtsqDET618M0 Salt: MDF2a3cxdmlDZzRK

Passlib: Hash: 2/9COWqb6SZG/raqabtU8fNBzkrt2puN7SaKw0U7jBs Salt: MDF3YXlGNUpMVlNa
Cracked: Hash: 2/9COWqb6SZG/raqabtU8fNBzkrt2puN7SaKw0U7jBs Salt: MDF3YXlGNUpMVlNa
```

Answer (score 3):

That format is used by Django and passlib have functions for that format: [Django 1.4 Hashes](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.django_std.html#django-1-4-hashes).

So, I did this in python's shell:

```
>>> from passlib.hash import django_pbkdf2_sha256
>>> secret = 'harry'
>>> hash = 'pbkdf2_sha256$10000$005OtPxTXhPq$K/2GplWPJsBVj+qbgdKW8YEteQyUkIiquT5MaOhPo4Y='
>>> django_pbkdf2_sha256.verify(secret, hash)
True
>>> rounds = hash.split('$')[1]
>>> salt = hash.split('$')[2]
>>> django_pbkdf2_sha256.hash(secret, rounds=rounds, salt=salt) == hash
True
```